# Disabling Gatekeeper in macOS Catalina (10.15.1)

Tags: security, macos-catalina

I am trying to run some command line tools, and every time it calls a new dependency I get the popup "X cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified." Obviously, if I open system preferences, I can click on "open anyway", but this is an incredibly onerous process for the tools I'm using.

I found the following supposed workaround:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

This enables a radio button labelled "Anywhere" under "Allow apps downloaded from", but it doesn't seem to actually have any effect on the screening of the command line tools. I still get the popups, and in fact, if I close system preferences and reopen it, the "Anywhere" radio button has disappeared.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `spctl --status` tell you after running `sudo spctl --master-disable`?

Comment: @Worthwelle, it says `assessments disabled`. But then it still threw me the popups

Comment: Try disabling the rearm feature with `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.security GKAutoRearm -bool NO` ([source](https://osxdaily.com/2015/11/05/stop-gatekeeper-auto-rearm-mac-os-x/)). It's only supposed to rearm every 30 days, but maybe it's doing it more often.

Comment: Still getting the popups. Is it possible there's a different option to be set for the commandline screening?

Comment: Would adding exceptions using the command line be sufficient for you? If so, try `spctl --add /Path/To/Application.app`. For reference: https://www.manpagez.com/man/8/spctl/ I don't think there are separate options for command line screening, but am not familiar enough to give an expert opinion on that.

Comment: I even went as far as `for i in lib/thirdparty/bin/*; do  spctl --add $i; done` just now, and still no dice!

Comment: It'a really seeming as if my only way forward is to let the thing run till it hits a binary it hasn't tried before, let it crash, click "open anyway", then click "open" when it comes back to it the next time....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104661/discussion-between-worthwelle-and-jofrhwld).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Catalina 10.15.7. `sudo spctl --master-disable` did not remove the popups, even though the status says `assessments disabled`.

What did work was additionally running `csrutil disable` in recovery mode. (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x)

This will completely disable SIP, so use your own judgement.